# Help needed in setting up rest api in CIVI CRM

Tags: api, webform-civicrm, rest

I tried below steps but I am getting an error in calling rest API via the browser.

1. I checked which user is an administrator and added api key via phpmyadmin interface.
2. Get the site key from CiviCRM settings.
3. I cross checked that user have permissions for editing and view contacts.
4. I want to get operation for contacts based on some condition.

Please have a look at error that I am getting.[image]

Setting file is present in same folder 
public_html/crm/sites/default

Please help me.It's the little bit urgent.
I am very thankful to you.

With Regards,

Mohit Thareja

Answer (score 1):

In your pictured error messages, I see `sites/all/modules/cv/civicrm` which looks a little strange. CiviCRM is typically installed at `sites/all/modules/civicrm`. I'm not positive this will help, but I would suggest trying the following:

1. Move the `civicrm` folder up into the `modules` folder.
2. Make sure CiviCRM still works via the regular front-end interface (and troubleshoot, as necessary)
3. Try your REST call again

Answer (score 0):

I've seen CiviCRM not behave correctly in a couple of other cases, both of which I believe have been addressed in recent releases but still might be worth investigating:

- Where a symlink existed as part of the site path. (eg, `/home4/mark` is actually a symlink to `/srv/userdata/m/mark`, or `/home4/mark/public_html/crm` is a symlink to `/home4/mark/project1/civicrm`)
- Where the CMS/CiviCRM was not installed to the webroot of the site. (This appears to be the case, eg Drupal/CiviCRM is installed at `http://example.org/crm/` rather than `http://example.org/`

If Sean's recommendation doesn't resolve your situation, you might investigate these potential causes as well.

In any case, please do update with the solution you find - it may help that being addressed in CiviCRM core and save you or other users similar challenges in future!